# ldap connection

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, ldap

my problem: I cant use my **addressbook from memotoo in Thunderbird or Evolution when connected via ldap**. I have a usual **Ubuntu 13.04**, without strange modifications. Config.([standard config](http://www.memotoo.com/de/index.php?rub=infoAnnuaireLdap)) and password-request were ok. But the ldap-addressbook is empty.

So I tried:

```
telnet ldap.memotoo.com 389
Trying 88.190.31.67...
Connected to dd32442.memotoo.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

The connection is closed "*by foreign host*". Who is foreign host closing my connection after 2 seconds?

```
lsof -i :389
COMMAND PID USER FD TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
evolution 9432 xxx zzz IPv4 1133648 0t0 TCP yyyy.myrouter:36446->dd32442.memotoo.com:ldap (CLOSE_WAIT)
evolution 9432 xxx zzz IPv4 1738153 0t0 TCP yyyy.myrouter:36612->dd32442.memotoo.com:ldap (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

NMAP:

```
nmap 88.190.31.67 -p 389
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at
Nmap scan report for dd32442.memotoo.com (88.190.31.67)
Host is up (0.038s latency).
PORT STATE SERVICE
389/tcp open ldap

nmap 127.0.0.1 -p 389
Starting Nmap 6.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at xxx
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000074s latency).
PORT STATE SERVICE
389/tcp closed ldap
```

NETSTAT:

While writing the contact name into the "TO" Field (Tbird), it is connected (automatic completion)

```
netstat -an | grep 389
tcp 0 0 192.168.178.25:51579 88.190.31.67:389 CONNECTED
```

Results:

1. LDAP-addressbook is empty
2. When writing an email, the automatic contact completion is not working

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be related [to a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=906663), so I added my experiences to the bug report.

I'd love to see that bug get fixed!